# Can we use TestNG with Selenium WebDriver and Cucumber?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng

if so what are Pros and Cons?example could be useful.Is it a  good way for Testing by using all these tools together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use them as any other combination of tools.
Would that combination be useful, depends completely on the problem you're trying to solve.

Speaking about the components,

- testng is just the test runner that can be used with cucumber and webdriver, but can be easily replaced by junit, for example
- webdriver is a defacto standard for driving web interfaces
- and cucumber is in fact [not a testing tool](https://cucumber.io/blog/2014/03/03/the-worlds-most-misunderstood-collaboration-tool) at all

So you'll have some benefits using cucumber as a way to improve your team communications (though there aremany other ways to do it); 
but you'll surely make your life harder trying to use cucumber+webdriver for writing regular automated tests.